# To split text file into multiple files using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

The idea of this batch script is to split a file that contains lines of information which separated by '//' and then name the file based on the timestamp along with a special keyword as the file extension. The file also contains a header that is required to be removed first before splitting the file. Sample of the main file:

- Main Header 1
- .....
- .....
- Main Header 8
- DOC (Sub header)
- Line1
- Line2
- Line3
- Line4
- Line5
- //
- TXT
- Line1
- Line2
- Line3
- Line4
- Line5
- //
- DOC
- Line1
- Line2
- Line3
- Line4
- Line5
- //

---

So basically, the batch script will convert the main header into '//' and then by using '//' as separator, the content will be broken into a separate file. And each file will be naming based on the timestamp (yyyymmdd_hhmmss) and the sub-header 'TXT' and 'DOC' as the file extension.
Example 20140914_001411.TXT or 20140914.013326.

- Sample of the individual file.
- TXT
- Line1
- Line2
- Line3
- Line4
- Line5

And no action is required if no keyword TXT or DOC is found in the main file.

Really appreciate if someone can assist me with this script.

Thanks/regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.   Unfortunately, this question falls into the category of "please help me with my homework" (even if it isn't your homework).   StackOverflow is for asking questions about code.  It's not for requests to provide code.   If you have a crack at the problem and bump into problems, you should come and ask about those.   See "off topic" item #3, here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "extensions=doc txt"
SET "datestamp=%date%_%time%"
FOR %%s IN (/ - " " . :) DO SET "datestamp=!datestamp:%%~s=!"

SET "output="
FOR %%a IN (%extensions%) DO DEL "%destdir%\%datestamp%.%%a" >NUL 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25829175.txt) DO (
 IF "%%a"=="//" (SET "output=Y"&SET "ext="
 ) ELSE (
  IF DEFINED output (
   IF NOT DEFINED ext FOR %%s IN (%extensions%) DO IF /i "%%a"=="%%s" SET "ext=%%s"
   IF DEFINED ext (>>"%destdir%\%datestamp%.!ext!" ECHO(%%a) ELSE (SET "output=")
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q25829175.txt` containing your data for my testing, but i removed the terminating spaces and appended a letter to each line of each data sectionin order that they could be individually distinguished.

Essentially, the `output` flag is set and the `ext` data cleared each time `//` is encountered. If we are outputting (`output` set) then if `ext` is not set, this must be the first line of a potential section, so it's checked and established.

If `ext` remains unset, then this section is of no interest, so clear the output flag, otherwise `ext` contains the section-id so output to that file.

You'd need to manipulate `datestamp` according to your particular requirements. Easily done - just consult any number of SO articles on batch substringing.